# Open an Application with another application only c#

Tags: c#, windows, security

As I have AppA.exe and AppB.exe. I wanted to run AppB.exe only through AppA.exe(Basically Work as Launcher).If I try to open AppB.exe Directly it shouldn't open or Do some Popup message"Open from AppA.exe". Or It should not open with any other application. I wanted to secure the AppB.exe.

Comment: Why do you need AppB.exe if it can be opened only by another program?

Comment: Think If AppB.exe is main Program, I wanted to update it through AppA.exe, But If you open AppB.exe open by another program it, update doesnt take place

Comment: Depending on your favorable level of application security, a rather simple/weak approach is to pass a parameter (as password) when starting AppB process. This parameter is checked at startup in AppB and  process is self-terminated when it is wrong.

Comment: It sounds like a better option would be for AppB to check for an update and run AppA and close itself to ensure that the update takes place. Think about how VS updates take place. You can run the VS installer first and run VS from there but VS will tell you when an update is available and you can run the VS installer from there. Of course, you could always use ClickOnce deployment and then all this goes away entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a method like Hamid Siaban commented: Pass a parameter when starting AppB.exe.

But be careful! It is possible to catch the parameter with free tools like Process Monitor or Process Explorer (both from Sysinternals).
If it should be a higher protection level, then you should calculate the parameter at runtime. Maybe based on the current time.

Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_one-time_password

You could use e.g. this library: https://github.com/kspearrin/Otp.NET